# Detecting iOS version and Testing

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7

I am facing a very strange problem while testing my application (built according to `iOS 7`) on `iOS 6`.

I have an `iPhone 5` and an `iPhone 4S` device that run on `iOS 7`. So, in order to check my app on `iOS 6`, i have downloaded the simulator for `iOS 6.1`. Also, i have changed the "`project Deployment Target`" in `project Settings` and `Target Settings` to `iOS 6.1`.

The strange thing is that while running the code below, everything goes expected as long as i am selecting:

```
1) iPhone retina 4-inch (iPhone 5) simulator in combination with iOS 7.0
2) iPhone retina 3.5-inch (iPhone 4S) simulator in combination with iOS 7.0
3) iPhone retina 3.5-inch (iPhone 4S) simulator in combination with iOS 6.1
```

However, as soon as i select

`iPhone retina 4-inch simulator(iPhone 5)` in combination with `iOS 6.1`,

the console shows

`iOS 6`, `iPhone 4S` and the screen size is 480

Here's the code that i am using:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        [prefs setObject:@"iOS7" forKey:@"iOSType"];

        if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
        {
            NSLog(@"iOS 7, iPhone 5");

            [prefs setObject:@"iPhone5" forKey:@"DeviceType"];
            [prefs synchronize];

            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"  bundle:nil];

            self.hpvc = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"iOS 7, iPhone 4S");

            [prefs setObject:@"iPhone4S" forKey:@"DeviceType"];
            [prefs synchronize];

            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone4S"  bundle:nil];

            self.hpvc = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController_iPhone4S" bundle:nil];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        [prefs setObject:@"iOS6" forKey:@"iOSType"];

        if (screenRect.size.height == 568)
        {
            NSLog(@"iOS 6, iPhone 5");

            [prefs setObject:@"iPhone5" forKey:@"DeviceType"];
            [prefs synchronize];

            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"  bundle:nil];

            self.hpvc = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"iOS 6, iPhone 4S and the screen size is %f", screenRect.size.height);

            [prefs setObject:@"iPhone4S" forKey:@"DeviceType"];
            [prefs synchronize];

            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone4S"  bundle:nil];

            self.hpvc = [[HomePageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController_iPhone4S" bundle:nil];
        }
    }
```

Why is this happening?? why am i not able to combine iPhone 5 and iOS 6 together???

Comment: here is the similar issue :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749463/unable-to-detect-iphone-retina-4-inch-screen-size-in-simulator?rq=1

Comment: @V-Xtreme: Thanks man..!! you saved my life..!!! I was stuck on this for hours..!!

Comment: Nice to here that it was worked for you. cheers !!